# How do I join multiple tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join multiple tables together but I can't seem to get it right. The error That I get back is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.egr_name = egr.name
            JOIN dirEgr
                dirEgr' at line 4
```

The SQL sintax that I have is the following

```
SELECT egr.*, carEgr.*, dirEgr.*, egrEmp.*, emp.*, boss.*, asoci.*, snip.*, pro.*
            FROM egr 
            JOIN carEgr
                carEgr.egr_name = egr.name
            JOIN dirEgr
                dirEgr.egr_name = egr.name
            JOIN egrEmp
                egrEmp.egr_name = egr.name
            JOIN emp
                emp.idEmp = egrEmp.emp_idEmp
            JOIN boss
                boss.emp_idEmp = emp.idEmp
            JOIN asosi
                asoci.egr_name = egr.name
            JOIN snip
                snip.egr_name = egr.name
            JOIN pro
                pro.egr_name = egr.name
```

egr_name is the primary key on most of the tables except for emp and boss. Also, how do I connect the boss to the egr table or egr_name primary key? My tables are:

```
egr
name

carEgr
egr_name //primary foreign key from egr table
idCarEgr //primary key
nameCarEgr

dirEgr
idDirEgr //primary key
egr_name //primary foreign key from egr table
nameDirEgr

egrEmp
emp_idEmp //primary key
egr_name //primary foreign key from egr table
nameEmp

emp
idEmp //primary key
nameEmp

boss
idBoss //primary key
emp_idEmp //primary foreign key from emp table
nameBoss

snip
idSNIP //primary key
egr_name //primary foreign key from egr table
nameSNIP

asoci
idAsoci //primary key
egr_name //primary foreign key from egr table
nameAsoci

pro
idPro //primary key
egr_name //primary foreign key from egr table
namePro
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `ON` clause for `JOINS`

```
SELECT egr.*, carEgr.*, dirEgr.*, egrEmp.*, emp.*, boss.*, asoci.*, snip.*, pro.*
FROM egr 
JOIN carEgr
   ON carEgr.egr_name = egr.name
JOIN dirEgr
   ON dirEgr.egr_name = egr.name
JOIN egrEmp
    ON egrEmp.egr_name = egresado.name
JOIN emp
    ON emp.idEmp = egrEmp.emp_idEmp
JOIN boss
    ON boss.emp_idEmp = emp.idEmp
JOIN asosi
   ON asoci.egr_name = egr.name
JOIN snip
   ON snip.egr_name = egr.
JOIN pro
    ON pro.egr_name = egr.name
```

Comment: The query works now but it is not showing anything. It only marks it as success without returning any values. Do I need the WHERE clause?

Comment: You haven't posted your exact requirement. `WHERE` will be needed to filter out records. Its not mandatory.

Comment: Figured out the problem. I erased some registers and that is why it was returning nothing. Although all the other should be showing because the main one is egr, the one that I erased were from carEgr.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrEmp.egr_name = egresado.name
```

Where is the reference for egresado. This is not defined. Change this and run your query in addition to above comments.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Not in the actual query I just wanted to add some more to be able to see how it would look like with more tables joined